# How do I pass multiple variables as data with gtk signals

Tags: c, gtk

I have a small program where a gtk signal callback function needs 2 or 3 variables.

I don't want to make these global variables (The entire goal of the project is to be neat and tidy) and I don't want to make a whole struct just so I can send a widget and a compiled regex to a function.

As far as I've seen `g_signal_connect` only allows for a single data variable.

Would the most efficient way of doing this perhaps be an array of void pointers to the two objects in question? Something like this?

```
void * data[2];
data[0] = widget;
data[1] = compiledregex;
g_signal_connect(save,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(callbackfunction),data);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course you can use arrays of void pointers, but if you want to pass around values with different types (especially values whose type is longer than `sizeof(void *)`), you can't use arrays. For these, you'll almost certainly want to wrap them in a struct and pass the struct's address as the data parameter.

Example:

```
struct my_struct *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
data->field_one = value_one;
data->field_two = value_two; /* etc. */

g_signal_connect(save, "clicked", callback, data);
```

Of course, don't forget to `free(data)` in the callback function (assuming it's for single use).

Edit: as you wanted an example with void **, here you are (this is ugly, and I don't recommend you to use this -- either because allocating a one-element array for primitive types is wasting your shoot or because casting a non-pointer to void * is bad practice...):

```
void **data = malloc(sizeof(data[0]) * n_elements);

type1 *element1_ptr = malloc(sizeof(first_item));
*element1_ptr = first_item;
data[0] = element1_ptr;

/* etc. */
```

To free them:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
    free(data[i]);

free(data);
```

Comment: But aren't pointers always the same size? Can't I just pass pointers to the variables in the array and dereference them inside the callback function?

Comment: @JV *in practice*, pointers are of the same size, so `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(char *) == sizeof(whatever *)`, but this is not guaranteed by C.

Comment: Also, it would be cumbersome to call `malloc()` for every single value's pointer *plus* the ecnlosing array - it's better to use it only once (as memroy allocation is an expensive operation).

Comment: I'd still much rather not use a struct, could you add a `void **` example to your answer?

Comment: From this example, you really should be able to rework it using a void **.

Comment: I'm getting a segfault and I have no idea why... I think my array is being destroyed after the signal is connected...

Comment: @JV are you using `malloc()` (**as I told you to do so**)? If not, that's natural - automatic variables, including local arrays, are invalidated upon tearmination of their scope (e. g. return from the function).

Comment: Oh I see, I would have to malloc the regex as well as the array (Not the widget, that's handled by Gtk anyway) - Yes I see why a struct would be beneficial. Nonetheless, it would still require you to define the struct for a single use. Isn't there a best-practice somewhere that despises that?

Comment: @JV that's called object-oriented programming design :) (and maybe a hash table)

Comment: One last question. Why do we initialize the struct as a pointer rather than initialise it as a struct and reference it later in the callback?

Comment: @JV You mean `struct mystruct data; data.value = 1; g_signal_connect(..., &data)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Shouldn't they both have the same result?

Comment: @JV I just explained it to you. Automatic variables are deallocated when the function which they've been created in returns.

Comment: But can't you malloc the struct itself rather than it's pointer, or is that not possible?

Comment: No, it isn't. How you would you do that?

Comment: Anyway, why would you want to alloc 'the struct itself'? The 3rd argument of g_signal_connect is big enough only to hold a pointer, not a whole struct...

Answer (score 7):

You can use g_object_set_data() and g_object_get_data(). First, set the data:

```
g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(my_edit), "my_label", my_label);
g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(my_edit), "age", GINT_TO_POINTER(age));
```

and in the callback you can get the data like so:

```
gint age = GPOINTER_TO_INT(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "age"));
GtkWidget *my_label = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "my_label");
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the data before destroying the object.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on H2CO3's answer, you can also set the data (and I strongly recommend using a struct, by the way) to be freed automatically when the signal handler is disconnected:

```
g_signal_connect_data(save, "clicked", callback, data, (GClosureNotify)free, 0);
```