# How to access a child widget with GTK+

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Here is how I built my Window :

- Window
- -- Grid
- ---- Menu Bar
- ------ Menu Item & Menu
- -------- Menu Item
- ...
- ----CustomWidget (DrawingArea)

When I click on a button in the menu, I call a function in which I apply a "get_path" on the widget and see this :

```
void Callback (GtkWidget * pWidget, gpointer * pData) {
    GtkWidgetPath * p = gtk_widget_get_path(pWidget);
    printf("%s", gtk_widget_path_to_string(p));
}
```

> GtkWindow.background GtkGrid GtkMenuBar.menubar GtkMenuItem.menuitem GtkWindow.background GtkMenu.menu GtkMenuItem.menuitem

I would like to access the CustomWidget from there.
How can i do this ?

I tried multiple get_parent ("not a Widget" since the third one), get_ancestor (returned NULL), get_toplevel (returned NULL) but it didn't work ...

Thanks !

Comment: Is `pData` actually of type `CustomWidget`? What is `CustomWidget`'s base widget it is derived from?

Comment: No, pData is a classical structure which doesn't involve GTK at all.
CustomWidget is actually a DrawingArea. All things considered, it's not that much customized ...

Comment: Could be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808819/how-do-i-pass-multiple-variables-as-data-with-gtk-signals